# Is it an offence if someone asks for an email address in a comment?

Tags: discussion

Let's say a new member of Stack Overflow asks a question, and there is a lengthy discussion between a senior member and a new user. Since new users don't have enough reputation to move the comment thread to chat, the new user asks for the senior member's email address to continue the discussion.

Is this regarded as offensive or not professional on Stack Overflow?

I think there should be a way to contact anyone on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should be more clear with your tags. Is this primarily a discussion? A support request? Or a feature request? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 11):

It's not professional. If someone want's to be contactable they'll include details of how to do that in their profile by listing things like their website, Twitter handle or Facebook page. If none of these are present **don't** go looking for them on the wider web - that could be seen as stalking and is not welcome.

It has long been said that Stack Exchange is not a social network and there have never been any plans to add such features to the sites. The emphasis of the sites is the Question and it's Answers. If you need a longer conversation than can comfortably fit in the comments then that's a clear sign that the question or answer isn't good enough and needs more information added to it.

The reputation hurdle to be able to participate in chat is not huge and should be possible for anyone to achieve with minimum effort.

Answer (score -1):

Two answers...

1. > I think there should be a way to contact any one in stackOverFlow

   No there should not be a way because this way all can know each other's email and stackoverflow will became another facebook may be...
2. > Is this offensive or not professional practice in stackOverFlow?

   No it is not an offence but it is up-to the other person to give it or not?